# Acumatica API Select Branch on top of page

Tags: api, acumatica

[image: I need to select branch from combo box at top of this page from API]

I need to select branch from combo box at top of the page using SOAP API call in C# for example (see screenshot). How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify Branch using login string, see below

user@Company:Branch

Answer (score 0):

In case of invoices screen we have content.FinancialDetailsLinkToGL.Branch field which should be set first.

Comment: you can set branch only in connection using next construction user@Company:Branch